# Is there a way to obtain the directory structure of a gitlab repo using python

Tags: gitlab, os.walk, python-gitlab

Is there a way to get a list of files and directories in the gitlab repo using python? So if I use the gitlab repository url as my source, can I traverse and get a list of all files and directories/ sub-directories within the repo? Like using `os.walk` but for a web url.

Comment: This above use case would be for hundreds of repositories so using something like subprocess is out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try [python-gitlab](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)?
Use `repository_tree` method can do it for you.
Here is the code

```
import gitlab

gl = gitlab.Gitlab.from_config()
# Get a project by ID
project_id = 851
project = gl.projects.get(project_id)
branch = {your branch}
directory = {your directory ref to root directory of the repository}
project.repository_tree(direcotry, ref=branch)
```

For more details, please visit [python-gitlab](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)